# How to extract HTML tag content with python HTMLParser

Tags: python, html

I`m processing HTML page and finally ended up with lines like this:

```
<td class="border">AAA</td><td class="border">BBB</td>
```

I need to extract AAA and BBB into variables wwith HTMLParser and i cannot figure out how to do it simply.
I cannot use any other parser, cause i`m limited in python tools.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will print the data within TD tags:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

inTD = False

# create a subclass and override the handler methods
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        global inTD
        if tag.upper() == "TD":
            inTD = True
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        global inTD
        if tag.upper() == "TD":
            inTD = False
    def handle_data(self, data):
        global inTD
        if inTD:
            print data
```

Comment: Many thanks for answer, this example is everywhere. Though, i do not find it simple. I confused with the fact that in order to do simplest thing, for what this module should be intended for , i need to  create subclass and rewrite something with something. I hope there is an easier way to do this, or i will just user regexp to parse .

Comment: Do what you want, but a) except for saving the items, this does what you want, b) its already written, and c) its only around 20 lines of code.  And you do know that HTML, in general, can't be properly parsed by a regex, right?  (Which is why things like HTMLParser exist.)

Comment: What does "rewrite something with something" mean?

Comment: Many thanks for explanation. I`m writing simple script and  try to learn a python same time, that is why i`m not intended to copypaste lines of code which i  do not understand completely. And i do not want dig too deep cause script is realy simple  and practically could be  written on shell. "rewrite something with something" - i wanted to  shorten answer a little. No offence.

Comment: Would you have an example using the HTMLParser to remove all HTML code but leave select tags intact?

Comment: @Jared: Parsers aren't intended to modify the data being parsed; they leave EVERYTHING intact.  You could use a parser to build new HTML with things missing from the original.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I have this stupid dataset from FBO.gov that has tags to label variables, but the DESC field has html all through it. Have a suggestion on a quick way to scrape all of the HTML out of it?

Comment: @Jared: You could write a parser to spit out everything it sees UNLESS it is within one of these "fields" you want removed: set a global flag when a "field" starts, which means "don't write anything" and reset it at the end of a "field".  Sort of the inverse of the example above.

Comment: Why use a global here instead of a class member? Seems totally inappropriate.